# My sorting is not returning correctly in Linq

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq

I am trying to determine why my sorting is not working. I'm not getting an error, method just returns list not sorted.

```
public IEnumerable<Customer> GetSubsetOfEmployees(int startRows, int maxRows, string sortExpression)
{
    NorthwindEntities ndc = new NorthwindEntities();
    var customerQuery =
        from c in ndc.Customers
            //https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/101-LINQ-Samples-3fb9811b
        select c;

    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(sortExpression)) sortExpression = "CustomerID";

    Dictionary<string, Func<IEnumerable<Customer>, IEnumerable<Customer>>> orderings = new Dictionary<string, Func<IEnumerable<Customer>, IEnumerable<Customer>>>()
    {
        { "CustomerID",  x1 => x1.OrderBy(x => x.CustomerID) },
        { "CompanyName",  x1 => x1.OrderBy(x => x.CompanyName) },
        { "CustomerID DESC",  x1 => x1.OrderByDescending(x => x.CustomerID) },
    };

    orderings[sortExpression](customerQuery.Skip(startRows).Take(maxRows));

    return customerQuery;
}
```

Comment: A bit more info needed. How is it not returning correctly?

Comment: I'm not getting an error so it returns records fine, but not sorted

Comment: you are returning `customerQuery`. Instead, you should `return orderings[sortExpression](customerQuery.Skip(startRows).Take(maxRows));`.

Comment: Please note also that ordering is done in memory in this case, not at the database. This is true because your are using a Function instead of an Expression.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are not returning the sorted collection.

```
IEnumerable<Customer> result = orderings[sortExpression](customerQuery.Skip(startRows).Take(maxRows));
return result;
```

Comment: The method 'Skip' is only supported for sorted input in LINQ to Entities. The method 'OrderBy' must be called before the method 'Skip'.

Comment: but this works....
   var sorted = orderings[sortExpression](customerQuery);

        return sorted.Skip(startRows).Take(maxRows);

Comment: Cool, thanks for my first stack overflow "best answer"